# when i write localhost on my web navigator, i got this page

Tags: php, apache, localhost

when i write localhost or even 127.0.0.1 on my web navigator to go to my apache, i got this website, instead of the usual debian localhost page, why? then minutes ago i could go to the default debian apache page, like that:

![click here to see the image][1]

but now, when i write localhost or 127.0.0.1 i got this page, why?

![localhost/127.0.0.1 page i got, click here to see][2]

Comment: restart `apache` and test again

Comment: check your proccess by this commadn : `sudo fuser -k 80/tcp`

Answer (score 0):

Best guess is Wifi Lock is listening on port 80. you should try changing the Apache port to 81 or something.

Answer (score 0):

It kept showing this wifilock.com page for me also. I went to " /etc/apache2/sites-available/ " and just removed all files except for " 000-default.conf ". Now it works perfectly.

I'm running a Kali Linux VM, and just typing in it's IP address into the browser from a seperate Ubuntu VM, so it should be the exact same things for Debian.
I'm pretty new to Linux, after trying countless things I've come across online this notion of mine finally worked, but hopefully hasn't messed anything up XD